# Remap CSV as an array using first row as keys

Tags: php, arrays, csv, sorting

Let's assume I have a CSV file, which looks like:

```
[Line 1]: ID, Name, Birthday,   Phonenumber, Email
[Line 2]:
[Line 3]: 1,  Jim,  1978-02-01, 555-23-256,  jim.doe@donotreply.com
[Line 4]: 2,  Mia,  1985-12-21, 555-23-876,  mia@donotreply.com      
[Line 5]: 3,  Wil,  1962-05-07, 555-23-456,  wil.doe@donotreply.com
```

Now I am trying to wrap my head around this question:
How can I parse this file with PHP to get the following array?

```
$people = array(

[1] = array(
       [Name] => "Jim",
       [Birthday] => "1978-02-01",
       [Phonenumber] = "555-23-256",
       [Email] => "jim.doe@donotreply.com",
       ),

...

);
```

Any idea?

Comment: [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Thanks. I know how to open the file and that I can read it with fgetcsv. My problem is how to resort this mess :)

Comment: Do you have an array of this data? It looks like `['ID, Name, Birthday,   Phonenumber, Email', '', '1,  Jim,  1978-02-01, 555-23-256,  jim.doe@donotreply.com']`?

Comment: Yes, I do ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `fopen` and `fgetcsv`

In order to do this you need to first write a function for retrieving the data from the CSV and storing it in a variable, the function below will do this using [`fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

**First, you'll need a function to read the CSV:**

```
function utf8_fopen_read($fileName) {

  $fc = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8//IGNORE', file_get_contents($fileName));
  $handle = fopen("php://memory", "rw");

  fwrite($handle, $fc);
  fseek($handle, 0);

  return $handle;

}
```

---

Once you've done this you'll want to manipulate the data you've just retrieved so you can create a multi-dimensional array of the results, populating the data into the associative keys like you described in your question.

Now we are going to make a call to the function above and store the results in `$data`, using a [`while`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop we are going to iterate through the entire CSV and store all of the information into `$people` row by row.

---

**Populating your array:**

```
$people = [];

if(($handle = utf8_fopen_read('path/to/csv.csv')) !== FALSE) {

  while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) {

    $people[$i] = [];

    for($c = 0; $c < count($data); $c++) {

      $info = $data[$c];

      if($i == 0) $fields[$c] = str_replace(' ', '', $info);
      if($i > 0) $people[$ii][$fields[$c]] = $info;

    }

    if($i > 0) $ii++;
    $i++;

  }

  fclose($handle);

}
```

Comment: Who said any sort of character encoding conversion was necessary here?

Comment: And assembling the array for a row with the proper keys could be handled a little more concisely using `array_combine`.

Comment: @CBroe I'll make the suggested edits using `array_combine`

Comment: @AksenP What result are you getting?

Comment: @AksenP The output matches the exact example provided by the OP, can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @AksenP I am using an actual CSV with the data in it provided by the OP, the output is correct, the OP has done the exact same as the output is correct, I assume you've done something wrong in your setup

Comment: @AksenP It does create a multi-dimensional associative array, as described by the OP, I'm running the code locally now and it is working.

Comment: @MarkOverton, perhaps because `fgetcsv` is parsing a row and creates array of values in while loop.